# Sort by length of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists, each with a varying number of elements:

```
my_list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1],
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [1]
]
```

How could I go about sorting `my_list` by the number of elements in each list? I'm looking for both ascending and descending orders.

Comment: The idea is the same

Comment: @vaultah Yes, I realized that after, thank you.